# welcome/goodbye using discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a bot that greets a user that joins a server. But make it so that the person is greeted in the server itself rather than as a DM (which most tutorials I've found teach you how to do).

This is what I've come up with so far.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel("channel id")
    await bot.send_message(channel,"welcome")
```

but, it doesn't work and instead throws up this error.

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\first bot\bot.py", line 26, in 
on_member_join
await bot.send_message(channel,"welcome")
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\discord\client.py", line 1145, in send_message
channel_id, guild_id = yield from self._resolve_destination(destination)
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\discord\client.py", line 289, in _resolve_destination
raise InvalidArgument(fmt.format(destination))
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: Destination must be Channel, PrivateChannel, 
User, or Object. Received NoneType
```

Comment: Can you print the value of `bot.get_channel("channel id")`? Is it what you expect?

Comment: it says "None", wow that isn't what I expected. So how do I turn that None into something that represents the main text channel where I want the greeting to be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing the correct id to [`get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel), so it's returning `None`. A quick way to get it would be to call the command

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def get_id(ctx):
    await bot.say("Channel id: {}".format(ctx.message.channel.id))

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

You could also modify your command to always post in a channel with a particular name on the server that the `Member` joined

```
from discord.utils import get

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = get(member.server.channels, name="general")
    await bot.send_message(channel,"welcome")
```

Comment: i tried adding the first block in. But an error saying AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'channel' came up

Comment: but adding the second one seemed to have done the trick and it works just fine! thanks!

Comment: `ctx.channel` -> `ctx.message.channel`.  The rewrite version offers these convenience attributes that the async branch doesn't.

Comment: it's not server, it's guild...`member.guild.channels`

Comment: @c0dezer019 This answer was for an older version, there have been some breaking changes since then, including renaming server to guild

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Patrick Haugh is probably your best bet, but here are a few things to keep in mind.

The `Member` object contains the guild (server), and the text channels the server contains.
By using `member.guild.text_channels` you can ensure the channel will exist, even if the server does not have a 'general' chat.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = member.guild.text_channels[0]
    await channel.send('Welcome!')
```

Comment: You're mixing some attributes from the rewrite version (`member.guild`) and async coroutines (`bot.send_message`).  You should probably change `member.guild` to `member.server` or `bot.send_message` to `channel.send`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='the name of the channel')
    await channel.send(f'Enjoy your stay {member.mention}!')
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow - you may have noticed your answer has been edited to add markdown formatting - please review these edits or play with the rich text editor a little on here and you'll be making beautiful posts in no time.