# How to make a welcome message in discord.py for all servers?

Tags: python, discord.py

Every server has different channels with different ids so how to make it work rather than this?

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await client.get_channel(881523740163313718).send(f"Thank You for joining {member.mention} check #rules hope you will be happy here :)")
```

Also, is it possible to make a file manager bot? Like creating text files and saving them?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! There are a few questions that are similar if not the same to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64760333/how-to-set-a-welcome-channel-discord-py, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156410/welcome-goodbye-using-discord-py, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62667213/discord-py-welcome-message-for-multiple-servers, etc. Do have a look through the links I've provided, they may prove to be quite helpful! Happy coding!

Comment: thx il see to it :)

Comment: Instead of using a `.txt` file, you can use a `.json` file, which is demonstrated in the third link's answer. Json files are easier to use and a lot more reliable. 

Could you explain what you mean by a 'file manager bot'? Does the bot create a new file as per the user's command, or are you referring to saving data given by the user?

Comment: @Bagle I mean it creates and saves file by proceeding with this command "k!createNsave <content> <file path to be saved > <file name>"

Comment: In that case, it is possible, but you should ask a separate question as this is not related to making a Welcome Channel message per server

Comment: Hmm yes ik that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the **system_channel** (Discord's welcome messages gets sent here):

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = member.guild
    channel = guild.system_channel #getting system channel
    if channel.permissions_for(guild.me).send_messages: #making sure you have permissions to send message
        await channel.send(f"Thank You for joining {member.mention} check #rules hope you will be happy here :)")
```

---

You can also find **the first channel from the top to which you have permissions**:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = member.guild
    for channel in guild.text_channels: #getting only text channels
        if channel.permissions_for(guild.me).send_messages: #checking if you have permissions
            await channel.send(f"Thank You for joining {member.mention} check #rules hope you will be happy here :)")
            break # exiting the loop so you won't send messages to multiple channels
```

Comment: Hey but for second code it will send the msg to all txt chnls right?

Comment: No. After finding the one it has permissions to it will quit from the loop (last line - `break` statement).

Comment: Oh yeah I'll try thx :)

Comment: You should not use "...check #rules hope..." to mention a channel, you have to use a proper fomat if you want the channel to be clickable.
You can use f"...check <#{channel_id}> hope..." or get the channel object and then f"...check {channel.mention} hope..."

Comment: Hmm yes ik that

Comment: @KristN it has error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'permissions_for'

Comment: Could you send the whole stack trace?
It seems like the channel/member was defined incorrectly so discord.py returns None istead of the correct object